# C# - Detect PictureBox overlap

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Is it possible to detect if a pictureBox is colliding with/overlapping with another pictureBox? Sorry for the vague question formulation.

Comment: why not? Get their `top` and `left` that's `y` and `x` respectively. Then get `width` and `height` then you can do the calculations, and it will be easy since they are only rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if 2 rectangles overlapped you can use [`IntersectsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool overlapped= pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox12.Bounds);
```

To find the intersection area you can use [`Rectangle.Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Rectangle intersectionArea = Rectangle.Intersect(pictureBox1.Bounds, pictureBox2.Bounds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rectangle.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Just give `Bounds` of both PictureBoxes to the method:

```
Rectangle unionRect = Rectangle.Intersect(pictureBox1.Bounds, pictureBox2.Bounds);
if (unionRect.IsEmpty) {
    // no intersecion
}
```