# c# - Get Rectangle of Form

Tags: c#, winforms, window, rectangles

I'm working on a car-animation in C# and want to test if the car is still in the Window. I created a form with the Windows-Forms Designer.

I have a Rectangle of the Car:

```
public Rectangle CarShape { get; set; }
...
CarShape = new Rectangle(Pos, new Size(28, 62));
```

And my Form1 Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Startcars();
    }
    //Here is my Question:
    public static Rectangle Window { get; } = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0),Form1.Size);
...
}
```

Here I get the Error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.Size'".

I also tried it with 'this', which appears to be also invalid in a static property. If I change the Property to non static, this gets invalid in the current context.

Later I'm going to check it with `if(!Window.Contains(car.CarShape))`

How can I get the Window as a rectangle or is there a better way of testing if the car is still inside the window?

Comment: Why declaring `Window`as `static`?

Comment: First, don't use Window as the name of your property, since is a common class in winforms. Second, that property can't be static since the Form1 class doesn't have a size, but the instance of the class has a size. Then do what Pikoh said.

Comment: How can I get the instance of the Form1? Do I have to make a new Form1()? Maybe a stupid question but I'm new to C#...

Comment: [`this.ClientRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Good Point, thanks.

Comment: @Lithium I didn't know that Window is a common class, thanks. Changed it to another Name.

Comment: @DamienFlury You're welcome, take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33985530/3110834) which is using a panel as car. Also if you need to check cars overlapping you can take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33846814/3110834). You may find them useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be trying to initialize your varible in the definition. Do this:

1- Declare the variable as:

```
public Rectangle win { get; }
```

2- Then in the form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Startcars();
    win = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.Size);
}
```

As @Lithium says in a comment, you shouldn't name `Window` to the variable, as it can be confusing. It's always a good idea to follow the [Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#

**Edit**

You should also be using [this.ClientRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `this.Size` (thanks  Reza Aghaei for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks, worked. Name of Property changed to Win instead of Window. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Form's `Size` property is not static so you can't use a static Property that returns the Form's `Size` property.

An easier way would be to use the [ClientRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
if (ClientRectangle.Contains(CarShape))
{

}
```